# Cakephp 3 paginator template with Bootsrap problem with sort()

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, cakephp-3.0

Currently using paginator sort link inside a bootstrap list like this :

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">

  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">Filtrer les résultats de recherche pour les tweets.</li>

  <li><?= $this->Paginator->sort('created','<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Les plus anciens',['escape' => false,'direction' => 'asc', 'lock' => true]);?></li>

  <li><?= $this->Paginator->sort('created','<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Les plus récents',['escape' => false,'direction' => 'desc', 'lock' => true]);?></li>

  <li><?= $this->Paginator->sort('nb_partage','<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Les plus partagés',['escape' => false,'direction' => 'desc', 'lock' => true]);?></li>

  <li><?= $this->Paginator->sort('nb_like','<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Les plus likés',['escape' => false,'direction' => 'desc', 'lock' => true]);?></li>

  <li><?= $this->Paginator->sort('nb_commentaire','<span class="glyphicon  glyphicon-comment"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Les plus commentés',['escape' =>  false,'direction' => 'desc', 'lock' => true]);?></li>
</ul>
```

I'm also using a paginator template like this

```
    <?php
return [
    'sort' => '<a class="list-group-item" href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a>',
];

?>
```

When I click on a link, it correctly displays the page and the clicked link changes class thanks to bootstrap,but not for the first two links that change classes both, all the other links work perfectly.

This is because they both sort on 'created'.

Is it possible to differentiate them so that when we click on the first or second, it changes the class not the other, as for other links.

Comment: what is the meaning of having two identical columns? It seems correct to me that if you click on 'created' both the header arrows change the same way

Comment: CakePHP 3 sort() does his sorting on the first arg, here 'created' the goal is to have to links, one for sorting on the most recent date and the other on the oldest. I know that putting 'false' to lock do the same in one link but i wanted to know if is it possible to use two links and that Bootstrap can tell the difference between the two to change the class by clicking on the link